# How to implement invisible watermark image in image using 3 LSB

Tags: matlab, watermark, lsb

I need to implement 3 LSB watermarking without using the existing functions in MATLAB.

I need my function to get 2 images, both gray-level, and preform watermarking using 3 LSB.

I tried the following, but the result of the original image subtracted from the new image is all zeros which means they are the same.

```
function [C] = Q2(image,watermark)
% clc;
% image=imread('moon.tif');
% watermark=imread('cameraman.tif');

[X,Y] = size(image);
rewatermark = imresize(watermark,[X,Y]); % resizing watermark to fit image

% iterate the 3 LSB of the watermark and set them to a copy of the original
% image 3 LSB
C = image;
for i = 1:X
    for j = 1:Y
        for k = 1:3
            if(bitget(rewatermark(i,j),k) == 1)
                bitset(C(i,j),k,1);
            else 
                bitset(C(i,j),k,0);
            end
        end
    end
end

subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(image);
title('Original');
subplot(1,3,2);
imshow(rewatermark) 
title('Watermark');
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(C)
title('Invisble watermarked'); 
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf,'name','Q2 - Results','numbertitle','off')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bitset(C(i,j),k,1)`, use: `C(i,j) = bitset(C(i,j),k,1)`

Except of OOP programing, MATLAB does not support references (or pointers).
Executing `bitset(C(i,j),k,1)`, does not modify the content of `C(i,j)`, it sets the relevant bit to 1, and return the modified value.

Note:
I recommend suing the high bits of `rewatermark` (bits 6,7,8) instead of the lower bits 1,2,3 that are mainly "noise" (but it depends on your objectives).

---

Here is a code sample:

```
%function [C] = Q2(image,watermark)
clc;
image=imread('moon.tif');
watermark=imread('cameraman.tif');

[X,Y] = size(image);
rewatermark = imresize(watermark,[X,Y]); % resizing watermark to fit image

% iterate the 3 LSB of the watermark and set them to a copy of the original
% image 3 LSB
C = image;
for i = 1:X
    for j = 1:Y
        for k = 1:3
            b = bitget(rewatermark(i,j), k+5); % Use the high bits 6,7,8 (instead of lower bits 1,2,3 that are mainly "noise")
            C(i, j) = bitset(C(i, j), k, b); % Set bit k to the value of b (1 or 0)
            
            %if(bitget(rewatermark(i,j),k) == 1)
            %    bitset(C(i,j),k,1);
            %else 
            %    bitset(C(i,j),k,0);
            %end
        end
    end
end

subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(image);
title('Original');
subplot(1,3,2);
imshow(rewatermark) 
title('Watermark');
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(C)
title('Invisble watermarked'); 
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf,'name','Q2 - Results','numbertitle','off')

reconstructed_rewatermark = bitshift(C, 5);
imshow(reconstructed_rewatermark);title('reconstructed_rewatermark');
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I will try it out, and yea it is a requirement to use those 3 last bits.

Comment: I clicked the check sign, hope thats that.